# Force Gitlab to retry webhooks on failure with Go

Tags: http, go, gitlab, webhooks

I want to watch for every events in a Gitlab project and store them in an external service. For this, I use Gitlab Webhooks. I made a little local HTTP server in Go that listens for Gitlab's POSTs and forward them to an external service. Hooks contains every information I needed so it seems that this architecture is fine:

> ```
> Gitlab > HTTPServer > External Service.
> ```

My problem is when the external service is down, I cannot manage to make Gitlab retry the failed requests. As the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html#webhook-endpoint-tips) says:

- *GitLab ignores the HTTP status code returned by your endpoint.*
- *Your endpoint should ALWAYS return a valid HTTP response. If you do not do this then GitLab will think the hook failed and retry it.*

It is very surprising that Gitlab does not have a proper way to ask for a webhook retry. I have to explicitly return an invalid http response. Moreover, I cannot find an API endpoint to list all failed webhooks and ask for resend.

Question: How to explicitly return an invalid HTTP response with the standard "net/http" library in order to force Gitlab to retry Webhooks?

Comment: A Webhook is not meant for two way communication. It is just a notification "Hey, event A [with values X,Y and Z] happened." It is the responsibility of the system receiving the webhook to ensure the information given is properly processed and retries are made until that happens. Classically, you would simply take the incoming event and persist it to a message queue. From there, it gets picked up by the actual processor, which only acknowledges the read in case the processing was successful.

Comment: I was hoping that Gitlab will maintain this queue for me but you are right. Let's do server side event persistence. Thank you for this great help !

Comment: Working on an example already. Depending on the scope, you might want to use NATS, but the example I work out works with dque.

Comment: It is possible to resend failed event manually via gitlab UI (edit the webhook, there is list of events and in detail of the event you can resend it). It is OK for few failed events. Unfortunately I didn't found any way how to do it via API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the comments, a webhook is a mere notification that an event occurred, and potentially some data is sent, typically as JSON data.

It is your responsibility to persist the event itself and the data you want/need to process that was sent with it. Below you will find a commented example. Note that this does not include incremental backoffs, but that should be easy to add:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "flag"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"

    "github.com/joncrlsn/dque"
)

var (
    bind        string
    queueDir    string
    segmentSize int
)

// You might want to add request headers and stuff
type webhookContent struct {
    Foo string
    Bar int
}

func init() {
    flag.StringVar(&bind, "bind", ":8080", "The address to bind to")
    flag.StringVar(&queueDir, "path", "./queue", "path to store the queue in")
    flag.IntVar(&segmentSize, "size", 50, "number of entries for the queue")
}

// The "webserver" component
func runserver(q *dque.DQue) {

    http.HandleFunc("/webhook", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // A new decoder for each call, as we want to have a new LimitReader
        // for each call. This is a simple, albeit a bit crude method to prevent
        // accidental or malicious overload of your server.
        dec := json.NewDecoder(io.LimitReader(r.Body, 4096))

        defer r.Body.Close()

        c := &webhookContent{}
        if err := dec.Decode(c); err != nil {
            log.Printf("reading body: %s", err)
            http.Error(w, "internal error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }

        // When the content is successfully decoded, we can persist it into
        // our queue.
        if err := q.Enqueue(c); err != nil {
            log.Printf("enqueueing webhook data: %s", err)
            // PROPER ERROR HANDLING IS MISSING HERE
        }
    })

    http.ListenAndServe(bind, nil)
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    var (
        q   *dque.DQue
        err error
    )

    if !dirExists(queueDir) {
        if err = os.MkdirAll(queueDir, 0750); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("creating queue dir: %s", err)
        }
    }

    if !dirExists(filepath.Join(queueDir, "webhooks")) {
        q, err = dque.New("webhooks", queueDir, segmentSize, func() interface{} { return &webhookContent{} })
    } else {
        q, err = dque.Open("webhooks", queueDir, segmentSize, func() interface{} { return &webhookContent{} })
    }

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("setting up queue: %s", err)
    }

    defer q.Close()

    go runserver(q)

    var (
        // Placeholder during event loop
        i interface{}
        // Payload
        w *webhookContent
        // Did the type assertion succeed
        ok bool
    )

    for {
        // We peek only. The semantic of this is that
        // you can already access the next item in the queue
        // without removing it from the queue and "mark" it as read.
        // We use PeekBlock since we want to wait for an item in the
        // queue to be available.
        if i, err = q.PeekBlock(); err != nil {
            // If we can not peek, something is SERIOUSLY wrong.
            log.Fatalf("reading from queue: %s", err)
        }

        if w, ok = i.(*webhookContent); !ok {
            // If the type assertion fails, something is seriously wrong, too.
            log.Fatalf("reading from queue: %s", err)
        }

        if err = doSomethingUseful(w); err != nil {
            log.Printf("Something went wrong: %s", err)
            log.Println("I strongly suggest entering an incremental backoff!")
            continue
        }

        // We did something useful, so we can dequeue the item we just processed from the queue.
        q.Dequeue()
    }

}

func doSomethingUseful(w *webhookContent) error {
    log.Printf("Instead of this log message, you can do something useful with: %#v", w)
    return nil
}

func dirExists(path string) bool {
    fileInfo, err := os.Stat(path)
    if err == nil {
        return fileInfo.IsDir()
    }
    return false
}
```

Now when you do something like:

```sh
$ curl -X POST --data '{"Foo":"Baz","Bar":42}' http://localhost:8080/webhook
```

you should get a log entry like

```
2020/04/18 11:34:23 Instead of this log message, you can do something useful with: &main.webhookContent{Foo:"Baz", Bar:42}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that See [GitLab 15.7](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/12/22/gitlab-15-7-released/#automatic-disabling-of-failing-webhooks) (December 2022) implements an *opposite* approach:

> ### Automatic *disabling* of failing webhooks
>
> To protect GitLab and users across the system from any potential abuse or misuse, we’ve implemented a feature to disable webhooks that fail consistently.
>
> - Webhooks that return response codes in the `5xx` range are understood to be failing intermittently and are temporarily disabled. These webhooks are initially disabled for 1 minute, which is extended on each retry up to a maximum of 24 hours.
> - Webhooks that fail with `4xx` errors are permanently disabled.
>
> All project owners and maintainers are alerted in the app to investigate and re-enable any failed webhooks.
>
> This feature is now available on GitLab.com and self-managed instances along with feature enhancements including [handling cold starts](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/375147).
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_7/Auto-disable_failing_webhooks-screenshot-nov-9.png -- Automatic disabling of failing webhooks]
>
> See [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/8083) and [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html#failing-webhooks).

So not only sending back "an invalid HTTP response" would not work, it would result in a disabled webhook, starting with GitLab 15.7+.

---

This has been improved with [GitLab 15.10](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/03/22/gitlab-15-10-released/#automatic-disabling-of-failing-group-webhooks) (March 2023)

> ### Automatic disabling of failing group webhooks
>
> To protect GitLab and users across the system from any potential abuse or misuse, we’ve implemented a feature to disable group webhooks that fail consistently.
>
> - Group webhooks that return response codes in the `5xx` range are understood to be failing intermittently and are temporarily disabled. These webhooks are initially disabled for 1 minute, which is extended on each retry up to a maximum of 24 hours.
> - Group webhooks that fail with `4xx` errors are permanently disabled.
>
> Users with the Owner or Maintainer role are alerted in the app to investigate and re-enable any failed group webhooks.
>
> By default, this feature is enabled on GitLab.com and disabled on self-managed GitLab.
> To enable automated disabling of failed webhooks for project or group webhooks, administrators of self-managed instances must enable the `auto_disabling_web_hooks` [feature flag](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/feature_flags.html).
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html#failing-webhooks) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/385902).